# Video meta data using python

Tags: python, meta-tags

I want to extract video meta tags using Python as described.
On [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999444/python-file-meta-tag-reading), I found kaa module which is not supported in Windows.

Can anyone suggest me a Python library that can work on across the platforms?

Comment: hachoir do not provide me the library :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you seen [Hachoir](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata/1.3.3)? It 'extracts metadata from multimedia files'.

The different file format parsers give differing levels of detail, but it might be what you are looking for. Here's an example of metatdata extraction from an AVI file:

```
$ hachoir-metadata pacte_des_gnous.avi
Common:
- Duration: 4 min 25 sec
- Comment: Has audio/video index (248.9 KB)
- MIME type: video/x-msvideo
- Endian: Little endian
Video stream:
- Image width: 600
- Image height: 480
- Bits/pixel: 24
- Compression: DivX v4 (fourcc:"divx")
- Frame rate: 30.0
Audio stream:
- Channel: stereo
- Sample rate: 22.1 KHz
- Compression: MPEG Layer 3
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, and also it does not support `.mp4` format.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [enzyme](https://github.com/Diaoul/enzyme) though the refactoring has caused the manual to become outdated.

Also, `ffmpeg` is a very powerful tool and you can read video metadata using the command:

```
ffmpeg -i <videofile> -f ffmetadata metadata.txt
```